# Python 3 - How can I attach a terminal and askpass to the repl

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing something in which I run shell commands from python. It works fine until I need to run as root. Then I get this:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

how can I make it prompt me for a password?
I don't want to store my password in my code and I don't want to disable the password.

```
from subprocess import check_output
result = check_output('sudo pacman --sync ' + package_name)
```